# Can we modify UDID added in iOS developer portal?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, developer-program

I have an ios developer account. I by mistake added a wrong device Id in my devices. Can I modify the device id? I am able to modify my device name but not device id.

What can be done?

Please help and suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't be done. You can only remove devices when you renew your subscription.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the input. So should I believe that I have wasted 1 device out of 100 devices?? (100 device is the limit for number of devices added for testing for an iOS developer)

Comment: @parth: you have. I'd love to be proved wrong of course; but think about it, if they let you remove or modify device IDs, then you would be able to overcome the 100 devices limit. You might try writing to dev support, though. How many device IDs have you used, if I may ask?